# C Pointer Assignment: wrong address and segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, fault, memory-address

I'm having a really weird problem here, hope someone can help me. That's the code.

```
Node *fct(Node *list)
{
  Node *node;
  node = list;
  ...
}
```

Usually everything runs smoothly, but in some random cases I get a Segmentation Fault. I debuged with GDB. Normaly the address of both list and node are 0x80d4000, but when the Segfault occurs, the address of node = 0x400. (list is still 0x80d4000).
I really don't see where this could possibly go wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have corrupted memory somewhere else. We need more code, the given fragment doesn't have any problems.

Comment: Lots of ideas, but without more code, can't know which idea is actually useful to your situation.

Comment: IT's not the code here that's wrong, it's whoever calls the fct() function that passes it invalid data. (likely it tries to pass the address of a member of something that's a NULL pointer)

Comment: check if the valgrind (http://www.valgrind.org/) memchecker tool can help you a bit more

Comment: as I have to implement my own malloc, there are probably 1000 possibilities where I could have wrecked the memory and to many lines of code to post here :( I think I just have to keep debuging. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough code to be sure, but I suspect that somewhere, you pass a copy of an address (a pointer) and make modifications on the COPY (like a malloc); instead of passing the address of this address (pointer on a pointer), so you actually modify the pointer and not one of its copies.

An example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
int dostuff(char* str)
{
    str = malloc(sizeof(char));
    str[0] = 0x42;
    return 1; // size of string.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* mystr = NULL;
    unsigned int strlength = 0;
    strlength = dostuff(mystr);
    printf("%s\n", mystr);  // Segfaults here: mystr == NULL.
    free(mystr);
    return 0;
}
```

So here is what's happening:

1. You create a new char pointer set to NULL (better if you want to realloc, for instance).
2. You pass its value (NULL) to `dostuff`. The function makes a copy of this value (with a char* type), and modify this copy.
3. printf accesses mystr for printing, and while trying to read from NULL[0] (0), will segfault.

The rest of the `main` isn't executed, of course.

Here is why someone can fall into that pit: Usually, when you use some pointer with a function doing some modification on it, you modify its *content*, and not its address. When you modify its address, you almost always (excepted in cases like this one) have the function modifying it to return its new address. Like in `address = malloc(size)`.

In the other hand, if you want to set a POINTER (and not is content obviously), you will need to pass a copy of its address to the function. Here is the working version of the code above:

```
int dostuff(char** str)
{
    (*str) = malloc(sizeof(char));
    (*str)[0] = 0x42;
    return 1; // size of string.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* mystr = NULL;
    unsigned int strlength = 0;
    strlength = dostuff(&mystr);
    printf("%s\n", mystr);  // Now works: mystr is allocated.
    free(mystr);
    return 0;
}
```

So remember: when in doubt, return the pointer and get the address of the other variables (`strlength` here). If not possible, be very caucious about the actual type of the data you're manipulating, and double check your addresses after modification.

I hope it helps.